# How to add m2e-wtp Maven JAX-RS Configurator to Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin, m2e-wtp

my colleague and I are working on the same project using slightly different versions of Eclipse.  He is using Juno and I am using Kepler.

Under Help->About Eclipse->m2e-wtp he sees this
[image]

But I am missing the Maven JAX-RS Configurator: 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have to enable JAX-RS, JPA and JSF in Preferences.

Preferences -> Maven -> Java EE Integration.

Read about it here https://community.jboss.org/en/tools/blog/2013/03/12/lets-go-to-kepler